# Add a comment as a tooltip anwhere in the page with WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, tooltip

Is there a way to place comments on a WordPress post in a specific place on the page? Like if I was tagging a photo on Facebook, adding a note to a Flickr image, or commenting on Soundcloud wave.

I'm wornking with a special e-book project, and we want to know if WordPress may be used to create a feature to allow the reader to click anywhare in the page to add a comment, that will be then showed as a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that of course but you'd probably have to write that logic yourself, can't find a plugin that does that. The Django Book does this; http://www.djangobook.com/about/comments/, and you could build that for WordPress if you'd extend the regular comment with some info on what paragraph in a post the comment was made on, and find out a way to keep track of a paragraph associated to specific comments. It does feel to me like a hard thing to do, maybe there is an existing solution for it, I don't know about that.